# How to add Subclipse plugin to the newer version of eclipse Java EE IDE??

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, subclipse

this is the new location of it 
 https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki
couldn't add this into JAVA EE Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a wiki page. You need to read what it says, not enter it into the Eclipse UI. The update site URLs are in the text of that page.

Comment: Got it  Thank you